# Function keys default

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I have a MacBook Pro with Touch Bar. Touch Bar shows default buttons for brightness, volume, play/pause, etc.

I know there is the option to add applications to the shortcut bar in system settings to have the function keys <kbd>F1</kbd>…<kbd>F12</kbd> on the Touch Bar, but I want them ALWAYS.

I need them for programming (and I'm lazy and don't want to change my behaviour — imho it is part of the job of my computer to adapt to me, not the other way around) and so I have added PHPStorm to the apps, showing <kbd>F1</kbd>…

The problem is, when I'm in my browser, calendar etc. Play, etc. is showing. So I never know whether I have to push <kbd>Fn</kbd> or not to pause the music.

Is there any way to make the display of the Touch Bar consistent?
And consistently showing <kbd>F1</kbd>…<kbd>F12</kbd>?

Answer (score 3):

You can only do that: [How to use function keys on MacBook Pro with Touch Bar](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207240)

> For some apps, you can make the function keys display permanently in
>   Touch Bar:
>
> 1. In System Preferences, choose Keyboard.
> 2. Click Shortcuts.
> 3. From the left sidebar, select Function Keys.
> 4. Click the “+” symbol, then navigate to the app and select it.
>
> Now when you open or switch to this app, Touch Bar always displays the
>   function keys.